# Simplify the following logarithm and If possible, write the following as a single logarithm

Tags: logarithms

$$\log_xy-\frac1{\log_yx} + \left(\frac1{\log_5x}+\frac1{\log_{20}x}\right)$$

I tried to enter it into a solver but it used things like IN I have not learned yet.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: I don't know how to type base of a log :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\dfrac1{\log_ba}=\log_ab$ and $\log_ab+\log_ac = \log_abc$. Hence
\begin{align*}\log_xy-\frac1{\log_yx} + \left(\frac1{\log_5x}+\frac1{\log_{20}x}\right) &= \log_xy - \log_xy + \log_x5 + \log_x20 \\
&= 
\boxed{\log_x100}.\end{align*}

Comment: Please do not answer questions which show no effort from the asker, as mentioned in the recent [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards)

Comment: thx for answer how did i not see this before